# Increment char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, performance, char, increment

I got an char array like this:

```
uchar myBytes[4] = { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0xFF };
```

What is the easiest/best way to increment the last element, propagating the carry to earlier elements? My result should be

```
0x01, 0x23, 0x46, 0x00
```

Comment: Do you really want to increment only the last 2 members of an array of 4???

Comment: This question is missing something important: You *seem* to want this treated as a big-endian ordered 32bit value, and simple way to promote carry through the octets, by the looks of it.

Comment: So, if the array contained 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, you'd want the output to become 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x8A?  And if the array contained 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, you'd want the output to become 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00?

Comment: The easiest way is to forget arrays and use `uint32_t`

Comment: You can use the array as part of an  union and then incrememnt the correspoding `uint32_t`...(*Take into account the endianness - In case it doesn't yu have to process it manually*)

Comment: @StoryTeller.: Yes you have to take into account the endianness

Comment: The easiest way is the one you know how to do. There's no best way. Please ask a specific answerable question.

Comment: @StoryTeller.: Well after all it will boil down to the "incrememnt individual elements and carry forward" if endianness doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the bytes starting by the end of the array and compare the new value with the old one. If it is lesser, that mean that the conversion of the (integer) sum, has been folded over UCHAR_MAX.

Here is a possible code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char myBytes[4] = { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0xFF };
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        // mBytes[i] is promoted to int and the sum is converted to unsigned char
        unsigned char newer = 1 + myBytes[i];
        if (myBytes[i] < newer) break;         // stop at first non overflow
        myBytes[i] = newer;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("0x%02x ", myBytes[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It gives as expected:

```
0x01 0x23 0x46 0x00
```

---

References from draft n1570 at 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers [conversions] (emphasize mine)

> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>   2 Otherwise, **if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type**.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) if (++myBytes[i]) break;
```

This is the simplest solution I can think of.

Comment: Or even `for (int i=4; i--; ) if (++myBytes[i]) break;`

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks

Comment: @ikegami That's a neat trick. However I had to think for 2 seconds to understand it, so I would probably avoid using in code that needs to be maintained.

Comment: @DuncanJones, Nonsense. It's an extremely common idiom. It *is* used in production code all over the place. If you haven't learned it yet, it's high time you do!